# How to show callback function's parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to show callback function's parameter to user?

I'm writing a pagination component for table by javascript.
And this is my component code. (not finished yet)

```
function ComponentPagination(paginationAreaID, pageViewDataCount , 
totalDataCount, ajaxUrl)
{

//div
var paginationArea = document.getElementById(paginationAreaID);

//prev button
var prevBtn = document.createElement("a");
prevBtn.textContent = "Prev";
paginationArea.appendChild(prevBtn);

//page buttons
var pageCount = (totalDataCount / pageviewDataCount);

for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i) {
    var pageBtn = document.createElement("a");
    pageBtn.textContent = (i + 1) + "";
    paginationArea.appendChild(pageBtn);
}

//next button
var nextBtn = document.createElement("a");
nextBtn.textContent = "Next"
paginationArea.appendChild(nextBtn);

//Use this method to set callback function
//The call back function called when user click page button <a> or 
//next or prev button.

this.addCallBack = function(onUpdatePagingMethod)
{
    // (example)
    var clickedButton;// = clickedButtonIndex;
    this.onUpdatePagingMethodCallBack = onUpdatePagingMethod;
    //and then it will call when update will neccessay
    //like  this.onUpdatePagingMethodCallBack(clickedButton, ajaxUrl);   
}
}
```

User will use this like..

```
<script>
windows.onload = function()
{
 //the total data is 105 and the page will show each 10 items
 var pagination = new ComponentPagination("pageArea", 10, 
 105,"/API/FileList");

 //Register CallBack 
 pagination.addCallBack( onPageUpdate );
}
```

And then the user will design the callback function which name is on PageUpdate.

But, user can't know the callback function's parameter info which 
addCallBack() method want.  Like This.

```
function onPageUpdate(/* hum? how should i know the parameter? */)
{

}
```

well.. In c or c++ have function pointer(maybe they use typedef), so it can limit the parametes numberand each type and user can infer how to design callback function and parameters meaning.

I have no ideas how to limit or invoke parameter info to user in javascript.
Is there have any ideas about this? The comment is only way to solve this problem?

p.s : Not like ts, i want only js.

Comment: _"But, user can't know the callback function's parameter info which addCallBack() method want."_ They can know ... if you tell them in your documentation.

Comment: Look at how libraries like jQuery, lodash, underscore.js, etc. describe their callback functions. BTW, requiring the user to define a specific function name is poor design, callbacks should be a parameter to the function the user calls to initialize your plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have any way to declare the signature of callback functions in code. You should put it in the documentation of your component, e.g.

> `onPageUpdate`: function(string argName1, object argName2, ...)

For an example, see how jQuery describes the callback function in [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

All function parameters are present in the [Arguments Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)
you do `console.log(arguments)` inside any function and it'll log all the parameters on your console.

Edit: 
predefining a signature of a callback isn't possible in JavaScript except via the usual way of documentation by a comment.

This is possible in TypeScript though, in a similar format. 
`public myCallback: (name: type) => returntype;`

Comment: He's not asking how to show the values of the parameters. He's asking how to tell the programmer of the callback what parameters it will receive.

Comment: @Barmar, added details.

Comment: he specifically said he's not interested in typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want the parameters you can use arguments:

```
function onPageUpdate()
{
   for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: He's not asking how to show the values of the parameters. He's asking how to tell the programmer of the callback what parameters it will receive.